# Angular Page optimisation, Reduce Page Load Time

Tags: angular, pageload, page-load-time

Angular Page optimisation, Reduce Page Load Time.

Ways to improve page load time except image optimisation, code minimisation in angular web page application.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @Roy Multipage angular website but having slow page load time. Image and code optimisation done already. It is hosted on AWS t2 micro instance.

Answer (score 0):

To Optimize the loading time of an angular page we can do the followings:
We have the possibility to use the lazy load concept which allows to load only used modules and this will avoid the loading of all the modules during the first loading. We can use a shared module to remove duplicated modules.

Comment: Sorry but not mentioned earlier, lazy load is there already integrated

Answer (score 0):

As you have done already with image and code optimization along with the lazy loading, so you could reduce loading time of your page by reducing `Angular` app build size.

`Angualr CLI` already provides production flag  `--prod` to reduce the build size and it helps greatly so always use production flag to reduce build size.

Another thing you can bundle the application. By creating a bundle of your application, all your `JavaScript` files will be clubbed together in a single file. For this, you can use [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) which does a pretty amazing job and bundles your `JavaScript`, `CSS`, and `HTML` files. `Webpack` will transpile your `Typescript` code to `JavaScript` which is easier to read for the browsers.

Though most of the server compresses the build on by own before sending to browser into `Gzip` but if yours not then compress your build into `Gzip`.